# Create python wheel based on platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-wheel, python-packaging

I am trying to package my python code into wheel file. My code dependecies differ based on the platform.
For example in Windows, I need `psycopg2` while in linux I need `psycopg2-binary`.

I have created two separate files: `requirements.txt` and `requirements_linux.txt` in my project.
Below is the detail of my 
**Setup.py**

```
requirement_file='requirements.txt'
if sys.platform == 'linux':
    requirement_file = 'requirements_linux.txt'
here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# setup method inside setup.py

setup(
...
...
install_requires=open(os.path.join(here,requirement_file)).readlines(),
...
)
```

Now I am creating wheel file using the command `python setup.py bdist_wheel` command from windows system.But the above code doesn't seem to work. When I run the wheel file in linux environment, it searches for `psycopg2` instead of `psycopg2-binary`. Am I missing something?

How can I create wheel files for other platforms like linux or Mac and have separate dependencies in them?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a very helpful problem description. If you're getting an error, consider to add the full error stack to your question.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python projects distributed as *wheel* do not contain the `setup.py` file. Therefore it cannot be run at the time of the installation.

The correct way to specify platform specific dependencies for *setuptools* is the following:

```
setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=[
        "LinuxOnlyDependency ; platform_system=='Linux'",
        "WindowsOnlyDependency ; platform_system=='Windows'"
    ],
    # ...
)
```

References:

- [Section "Declaring platform specific dependencies" of `setuptools` documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-platform-specific-dependencies)
- [Section "Environment Markers" of *PEP 508*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers)